# FilePikcer upload file option is not showing in iOS 9

Tags: ios9, filepicker.io

I have implemented the **filepicker.io** in my iPhone application.
I am able to download file from cloud storage in iOS 7 and iOS 8 using SDK version 3.2.9.

Upload file is not displaying when running my app in iOS 9 and What will be the way to sort out this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you use official Filepicker iOS / OS X Library?  https://github.com/Ink/ios-picker

Comment: Yes, I am using Ink Filepicker iOS Library and I have followed this instructions "https://github.com/Ink/ios-picker/wiki/1.1-iOS-Integration"

Comment: Looks like it need to be updated to iOS9

Answer (score 0):

The bug is fixed in version 5.0.1 that is available on Github and CocoaPods.